# How to add a checkmark to the selected one and remove it from the rest of the inactive elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add a check mark to the selected one and remove it from the rest of the inactive elements ?

In this code, the checkmark is displayed on all elements. It should be on the first element by default and when clicking on another element, it should be opposite the selected one

```js
function dropdownCity() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdownCity").classList.toggle("showCity");
}
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches('#myDropdownCity a')) {
        myDropdownCity.classList.remove('showCity')
        document.querySelector('.dropbtnCity').innerText =     event.target.classList.add('checked').innerText
        const a = document.querySelector('.a')
        const b = document.querySelector('.b')
        const c = document.querySelector('.c')
        const d = document.querySelector('.d')
    }
})
```

```css
.checked::after {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    content: "✓";
    margin-top: -13px;
}
.dropbtnCity {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #303030;
}
.dropbtnCity:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: all ease 0.4s;
}
.dropdownCity {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-contentCity {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 197px;
    height: 164px;
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.dropdown-contentCity a {
    margin-top: -2.5px;
    color: #303030;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transition: all ease 0.2s;
}
.dropdown-contentCity a:hover {
    margin-top: -2.5px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    color: #303030;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.showCity {
    display:block;
}
.rectangle_container {
    margin-left: 135px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dropdownCity()" class="dropbtnCity">ACTIVE</button>
<div id="myDropdownCity" class="dropdown-contentCity">
    <a href="#myDropdownCity" class="a">ACTIVE</a>
    <a href="#myDropdownCity" class="b">ONE</a>
    <a href="#myDropdownCity" class="c">TWO</a>
    <a href="#myDropdownCity" class="d">THREE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `const a = document.querySelector('.a')` - the element with the class `a` exists, so it will be found, and so `if(a)` will also always be true.

Comment: After your initial if condition check passes, you already have the link that was clicked in `event.target`. So remove the class from _all_ links first, and then add it for the current one. (That should happen within the if block then, not after it, if you don't want to remove the class when the user clicks just *anywhere*. in the page.)

Comment: @CBroe, If I move the entire if / else block to if (event. target), then when you click on any element from the list, checkmarks appear on all elements

Comment: @CBroe   if (event.target.matches('#myDropdownCity a')) {
    myDropdownCity.classList.remove('showCity')
    document.querySelector('.dropbtnCity').innerText = event.target.innerText
    const a = document.querySelector('.a')
    const b = document.querySelector('.b')
    const c = document.querySelector('.c')
    const d = document.querySelector('.d')
    if(a) {
      a.classList.add('checked')
    } else {
      a.classList.remove('checked')
    }
  }

Comment: a) that is hard to read in comments, please edit your question and add the new code in there, properly formatted. b) You are still doing the `if(a)` thing, despite I already told you that this does not work the way you thought it should.

Comment: @CBroe, I answered my own question, now it works, but on the first click it does not show a checkmark due to the double addEventListener, how to fix this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean, double event listener?

Comment: @CBroe, In the function in my answer, everything works, but I had to apply a second addEventListener inside forEach, and it turns out that I have window.addEventListener and inside addEventListener, so it only works with two clicks, I don’t know how to fix it

Comment: No, those extra event handlers make little sense. (Plus, you'd be adding _new_ click handler each time, so they will accumulate.)

Comment: @CBroe, That's why I want to know how to replace it, can you help with this?

Comment: As I said: _"So remove the class from all links first, and then add it for the current one."_ You don't need your a, b, c, d variables. `document.querySelectorAll('#myDropdownCity a').forEach(...)` - in that loop, remove the class. And then after the loop, add it again on `event.target`.

Comment: @CBroe, i Fixed everything, moved it out of scope if(event.target)

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropdownCity() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdownCity").classList.toggle("showCity");
}
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('#myDropdownCity a')) {
    myDropdownCity.classList.remove('showCity')
    document.querySelector('.dropbtnCity').innerText = event.target.innerText
    const a = document.querySelector('.a')
    const b = document.querySelector('.b')
    const c = document.querySelector('.c')
    const d = document.querySelector('.d')

    let links = [a, b, c, d]
    links.forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', () => {
        links.forEach(a => a.classList.remove('checked'))
        link.classList.add('checked')
      })
    })
  }
})
```